# printf not printing past '.' in string

Tags: unix, awk, formatting, printf

I am having a problem using printf on my unix system. It is throwing an error every time I try to print the following

```
printf "%-15s %-15.2s" "Total Acounts:\nChecks=$" checks
```

checks should be a decimal, but I have tried printing it as a float and a decimal and get the same error.

```
fatal: not enough arguments to satisfy format string
    `%-15s %-15.2sTotal Acounts:
    Checks=$2135.92'
                ^
```

I have been working at this for a while now and can't figure it out, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `checks` a variable? Don't you mean to use `$checks`?

Comment: Checks is a variable. Sorry I should have said it's an awk script also

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not how you call `printf` in awk. You are missing the commas indicating arguments.

You've given `printf` only a format string (the concatenation of `"%-15s %-15.2s"`, `"Total Acounts:\nChecks=$"` and the value of `checks`).

As you can see from the error message that shows the entire string as the format string and includes the value of `checks` in the string.

You probably meant:

```
printf "%-15s %-15.2s", "Total Acounts:\nChecks=$", checks
#---------------------^---------------------------^
```

though `%-15s` there isn't really doing anything useful for you as `"Total Acounts:\nChecks=$" is longer than 15 characters.

Comment: wouldn't the last token be `%15.2f` to account for money in `checks`? Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter I agree that `%s` there is potentially odd but that was the OPs code and I wasn't going to change it.

Comment: I expected an error with this test, `awk 'END{printf("%s\t%-15.2s\n", "string", 2350.88)}' /dev/null` BUT it returned `string  23` . Hm, that's sort of an error ;-! Go figure.

Comment: @shellter With `BEGIN` you don't need `/dev/null` (at least with GNU awk). Not an "error" though certainly not what I'd expected. That is defined behavior from POSIX it would seem. The precision in a `%s` specifier is the maximum number of bytes to read from the string. Which is quite a handy shorthand I'll have to remember.

Comment: Ah, so its a feature? :-) Good luck to all.